# android : YouTubePlayerView video not visible

Tags: android, video, android-youtube-api

i am inflating a layout over the cameraview . The layout is like this

```
{ Linerlayout
    Relativelayout
       YouTubePlayerView   }
```

This inflated layout elements are initilly invisible and on user action these are made visible and i call

youTubeView.initialize()

the initialise finish listenr will call

```
player.cueVideo(getVideoUrl());
```

Now i can see the progressindicator first, then i can see the thumbnail of the video with play control on top. When i press that play button , the video start playing but nothing is visible. I can see my cameraview ( ie the view when we open camera )( over which this layout is inflated ) . The video sound is coming and the video is played. Now if i press fullscreen button, it opens video in full screen and here everything is fine. I can see the video . If i go back to small screen again no video only sound.

```
youTubeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toplayerLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        toplayerRelLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY,
                (OnInitializedListener) applicationActivity);
```

Please give some pointers on what could be happening

Please help as i am totally blocked

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the cameraview . I dont know why youtubeplayer view behaves like this . But i made the GLview ( camera ) invisible before making the youtubeplayerview visible and it is working .